# i want to convert this xml to c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
    <Width>6.5in</Width>
    <Body>
        <Height>2in</Height>
    </Body>
    <rd:InitialLanguage>true</rd:InitialLanguage>
    <rd:InitialDimensions>
        <rd:UnitType>Inch</rd:UnitType>
        <rd:LeftMargin>1in</rd:LeftMargin>
        <rd:RightMargin>1in</rd:RightMargin>
        <rd:TopMargin>1in</rd:TopMargin>
        <rd:BottomMargin>1in</rd:BottomMargin>
        <rd:PageWidth>8.5in</rd:PageWidth>
        <rd:PageHeight>11in</rd:PageHeight>
        <rd:ColumnSpacing>0.5in</rd:ColumnSpacing>
    </rd:InitialDimensions>
    <rd:InitialDimensions>
        <rd:UnitType>Cm</rd:UnitType>
        <rd:Width>16cm</rd:Width>
        <rd:Height>5cm</rd:Height>
        <rd:LeftMargin>2.5cm</rd:LeftMargin>
        <rd:RightMargin>2.5cm</rd:RightMargin>
        <rd:TopMargin>2.5cm</rd:TopMargin>
        <rd:BottomMargin>2.5cm</rd:BottomMargin>
        <rd:GridSpacing>0.25cm</rd:GridSpacing>
        <rd:PageWidth>21cm</rd:PageWidth>
        <rd:PageHeight>29.7cm</rd:PageHeight>
        <rd:ColumnSpacing>1cm</rd:ColumnSpacing>
    </rd:InitialDimensions>
</Report>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to serialize this into a C# class? For that you can use XSD.EXE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) on how to parse XML. Since you don't seem to have a specific question, here a sample on how you could read the value of the first Width element in your xml:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
var width = doc.Descendants("Width").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, generate a schema for the xml:

```
xsd.exe "yourXml.xml"
```

This will generate a `yourXml.xsd` file containing a xml schema. Verify that this schema describes what you want reflected in your class.

Once your satisfied with the schema, use `xsd.exe` to generate classes:

```
xsd.exe "yourXml.xsd" /c
```

*note: if you want to generate a `DataSet` class instead, use `/d`.*